# Microsoft Access won't show query if date is empty?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

**--SOLVED--**

I'm having a problem with a query in Microsoft Access.

I need this query to show a list of entries where a specific **Date field is empty**. So it must sort and still show all the data, but only for entries where that specific date is missing.

There are a lot of dates in the table.

When I create a filter or just add criteria to the specific field in "Design View", it runs the query but it's empty without fail every time.

The field format is naturally a "Date" type field in the table.

I hope anyone can help me.

Thank you.

SQL BELOW:

```
SELECT rptClaimDateEmpty.Claim_Date, *
FROM (SELECT tblContainers.*, tbluCommodities.Commodity, 
tbluContainerSizes.ContainerSize, tbluCountryOfLoading.CountryOfLoading, 
tbluCountryOfOrigin.CountryOfOrigin, tbluShippers.Shipper, 
tbluShippingLines.ShippingLine, tbluPortOfLoading.PortOfLoading, 
tblBOLDates.BOLNumber FROM tblBOLDates INNER JOIN (tbluPortOfLoading RIGHT 
JOIN (tbluShippingLines RIGHT JOIN (tbluShippers RIGHT JOIN 
(tbluCountryOfOrigin RIGHT JOIN (tbluCountryOfLoading RIGHT JOIN 
(tbluContainerSizes RIGHT JOIN (tbluCommodities RIGHT JOIN tblContainers ON 
tbluCommodities.CommodityID = tblContainers.CommodityID) ON 
tbluContainerSizes.ContainerSizeID = tblContainers.Container_SizeID) ON 
tbluCountryOfLoading.CountryOfLoadingID = 
tblContainers.Country_of_LoadingID) ON tbluCountryOfOrigin.CountryOfOriginID 
= tblContainers.Country_of_OriginID) ON tbluShippers.ShipperID = 
tblContainers.ShipperID) ON tbluShippingLines.ShippingLineID = 
tblContainers.Shipping_LineID) ON tbluPortOfLoading.PortOfLoadingID = 
tblContainers.Port_of_LoadingID) ON tblBOLDates.BOLDateID = 
tblContainers.BOLDateID)  AS rptClaimDateEmpty;
```

I just need it to sort via the the "Claim Date" field where "Claim Date" is empty.

Comment: Can you show the query?

Comment: I will show it now. Give me 5 mins please. I'm just using the normal query design tool for this.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I edited my original post. It needs to show the entries where "Claim Date" is empty. The user didn't choose a date since that date can be chosen at a later stage depending on other factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't it just be:

```
SELECT *
FROM (...) AS rptClaimDateEmpty
WHERE rptClaimDateEmpty.Claim_Date Is Null;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man this worked. I tried the null with the criteria but it didn't work. Definitely going to look into the SQL itself more. Still a bit new to this and sometimes obvious things like that fly by me.

Thanks again!